# Can application descriptor give the other application descriptor in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

I want to know that can currentApplicationDescriptor() method of ApplicationDescriptor class give the another third party application descriptor...

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[CodeModuleManager](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/net/rim/device/api/system/CodeModuleManager.html) is what you want

Its not an application descriptor, since that just parses your XML into the class members. But it does read the info on other applications.